# How to make raster DEM from SHP with FME?

Tags: raster, dem, fme-form

I have a Point Featureclass in an ESRI FGDB with 22 Million points. The points have a distance of 10m from each other.I would like to create a raster DEM using SAFE FME 2014. Looking at the transformers, I can´t see a logical way to do this. Is there any standard methods to do this, or is FME really not suitable for this? I do have Spatial Analyst at my disposal but I wanted to try FME because it is usally 100 times quicker than ArcGIS.

Comment: Have you had a look at the RasterDEMGenerator in the surfaces category?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, FME has two DEM Generators.  They are called, appropriately, **[DEMGenerator](http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Transformers/Default.htm#Transformers/demgenerator.htm)** and **[RasterDEMGenerator](http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Transformers/Default.htm#Transformers/rasterdemgenerator.htm)**.

You'll want to use the RasterDEMGenerator.  There are several options for tweaking the output:

[image]

I recently used this tool to process about twice as many points and it took 2 hours and 45 minutes.  There were five XYZ files writing directly to the DEM.  I'd be interested to see how long it takes for you.  Might be more efficient if the points are already in an FGDB.